# Black and white display in windows, but not in linux

Tags: linux, windows-10

My issue here is a very weird one. I just had a power-surge in my room and then my windows display went black and white. The display is B&W but screenshots that I take in windows aren't B&W, as is evident when I transfer them to my phone to look at them. The boot screen is in its normal blue and when I boot Linux, colors work perfectly. Any ideas?

Windows 10, deleted my entire  `Users/$MyName$/AppData/Local/Temp` folder before the surge. The delete was done by then and colors were still working.

Comment: What about bios? Is it also showing up as black and white?

Comment: @Don'tRoothereplz... My BIOS was always B&W

Comment: got a different video port? update drivers lately? system restore?

Comment: @TonyStewart nope, didnt update any drivers recently, and no system restore. If I use the motherboard HDMI, the picture isn't even outputted, and I can only see the image if I plug HDMI into my Graphics card (NVIDIA GTX 960, if that helps). Also I moved everything back into my `Temp` folder and restarted, no change. :/

Comment: then try updating or removing drivers, or try safe mode to confirm it is the driver

Comment: Something just happened. I have a saturation toggler for CS:GO, and when I changed the saturation, then changed it back, I got my color back. what?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have pressed Window + Ctrl + C button by mistake. This shortcut toggles the default color filter.Currently your default color filter is GrayScale and by default filter set to Off.

There are two solution to the problem :

1. Press again Win + Ctrl + C to toggle off the filter

Or

2.

Open Settings.
Click on Ease of Access.
Click on Color & high contrast.
Under "Color filters," turn Off the Apply color filter toggle switch.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand why this actually happened, but When I changed the saturation using my `CS:GO Saturation toggler`, I got my color back, and it stayed across restarts. [Link in case you need it](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/28i4vk/saturation_toggler_v12/)